# POI Excel - Text cell that contains Numerical value is being recognized as Numerical Cell

Tags: excel, apache-poi

If I put number (like 2009, 345) into a Excel cell, I changed the Cell Format to "Text". 
When I use POI to read that cell, it still thinks it is a numerical cell.

Anyone had the same issue ? I am on POI 3.8.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POI isn't magic, it'll give you back what the excel file says is there!

In many cases, if you put a number into a cell, Excel will write that to the file as a number with formatting.

If you want a String back of what Excel displays, use [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) to have the number formatted as per the styling rules on the cell

Comment: I guess I didn't explain this clearly.  I changed the Cell Type to Text, in order words I explicitly told Excel it is a String in that cell.

Comment: IIRC, That changes the formatting rules applied to a number cell, rather than actually changing the underlying storage. To force it to be a String cell, you need to type in '1.2 rather than just 1.2 (i.e. prefix with a single quote)